# Bypass Old Hyperlink Error

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have the following issue:

I have a macro script for excel which is running through more then 300 excel workbooks,with several sheets.
The problem is that some of this sheets have faulty hyperlinks and each time I run the macro,the pop-up message informing me that the hyperlink found in the sheet is not working and I have to click each time , : ,,cancel'' . Is there a way (code) that I can write that will automatically  ,,cancel'' the pop up question ,if it appears?

Comment: Try sandwiching the code between `Appliction.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Appliction.DisplayAlerts = True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bypass this by wrapping your code in:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

-- your code --

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the privacy options are related?
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-about-links-to-and-files-from-suspicious-web-sites-HA010039898.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your hyperlinks were pointing to a worksheet's cells, and that worksheet may no longer exist, the best thing to do may be to simply remove those hyperlinks.

This is how you'd do this :

```
Sub RemoveDeadHyperlinks()

    For Each hyperL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks

        'Extract name of the sheet from the subaddress
        toSheet = Left(hyperL.SubAddress, InStr(hyperL.SubAddress, "!") - 1)

        If WorksheetExists(toSheet) Then

            'Most likely a valid hyperlink!

        Else

            'Most likely a dead one!
            hyperL.Delete

        End If

    Next

End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```